# Как сохранить картинку из Image в заданный каталог в WPF, используя SaveFileDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
string FilePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(FilePath));
string WayToSave = "D:\\3й семестр\\c#\first_lab\\WpfApp1\\WpfApp1\\Posters.jpg";
saveFileDialog1.FileName = WayToSave;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Answer (score 3):

Похоже, что вы не до конца понимаете назначение диалогов открытия и сохранения файлов.

Эти диалоги, в вашем случае `SaveFileDialog`, предназначены для получения корректного полного имени файла, или списка файлов, в случае множественного выбора в `OpenFileDialog`. Также они позволяют получить подтверждение пользователя, перед выполнением чтения или записи.

Непосредственно чтение и запись в файлы производится обычным способом, с помощью методов статического класса `System.IO.File` или потока `System.IO.FileStream`.

В документации [пример использования](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.win32.savefiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7) оказался не очень хорошим, поэтому, чтобы стало понятнее, дополню исходный пример непосредственно записью:

```
// Настраиваем параметры диалога
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Имя по-умолчанию
dlg.DefaultExt = ".text"; // Расширение по-умолчанию
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Фильтр по расширениям

// Показываем диалог пользователю
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Обработка результата работы диалога
if (result == true)
{
    // Получаем из диалога полное имя файла
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
    //Данные для записи. Тут для примера, это должно быть за пределами данного кода
    string someText = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm";
    // Сохраняем someText в файле, с полученным из диалога, именем
    File.WriteAllText(filename, someText);
}
```

Работа с диалогами, хорошо показана в примерах для диалогов WinForms. Разумеется придется адаптировать код примеров под целевую платформу.

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так вышло.

```
private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
       SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog
       {
            Filter = "JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg"
       };
       if (save.ShowDialog() == true)
       {
            JpegBitmapEncoder jpegBitmapEncoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            jpegBitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(img.Source as BitmapSource));
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(save.FileName, FileMode.Create))      
                jpegBitmapEncoder.Save(fileStream);               
       }
}
```